# WPF Global Hotkey using the mouse button

Tags: c#, wpf

So, I'm using this example to create a global hotkey in a WPF application:

https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/

It's pretty straightforward and works fine... but whenever I try to change the key to the mouse button, the middle one for example, it just does not work... In the list of keys from msdn, there is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

VK_MBUTTON 0x04 Middle mouse button (three-button mouse)

Whenever I try to change the hotkey to any listed key, it works fine, except for mouse buttons.. anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is a **key** so can be registered as an `HotKey`. The mouse middle button is a **button**, not a key. You simply can't use the same native method/code.

I suggest you to adopt the [globalmousekeyhook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) library for your application. In this case the sample that you find on [Magnus Montin's blog](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2015/03/31/implementing-global-hot-keys-in-wpf/) will become:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IKeyboardMouseEvents m_GlobalHook;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        m_GlobalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
        m_GlobalHook.MouseClick += m_GlobalHook_MouseClick;

        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    }

    private void m_GlobalHook_MouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            tblock.Text += "Middle mouse button clicked" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        m_GlobalHook.MouseClick -= m_GlobalHook_MouseClick;
        m_GlobalHook.Dispose();

        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
}
```

The only problem is that globalmousekeyhook library refers to System.Windows.Forms assembly and I do not know if it can be acceptable for you.

Comment: What would be the problem with windows.forms? I can't use it in a WPF application?

Comment: You can use it @raphadko in a WPF application. The point is that you are referencing a not strictly necessary assembly (WPF applications can work without System.Windows.Form assembly)